# DSN-less connection to MS SQL with Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, linux, perl, odbc

I'm looking for a way to connect from a Linux server, to MS SQL Server.  I was able to do so in a variety of ways but I want the connection to be DSN-less, uses Windows Authentication and preferably for Perl.  I know ADO can do so but I don't think it's available on Linux.

What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

There are various commercial ODBC drivers for Linux and one free solution I know of.

The [Easysoft SQL Server ODBC Driver](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-sql-server-driver/index.html) certainly provides windows authentication and DNS-less connections using a connection string like "DRIVER={Easysoft ODBC-Access Driver};Server=myserver;Port=myport;USER=mydomain\myusername;Password=mypassword".

There are a few other commercial ODBC Drivers from Openlink and DataDirect but I have no experience with either of them.

There is also [freeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/) which is open source and can probably do windows authentication but here again, I've not personally tried windows authentication with it.

As for Perl you need the DBI and DBD::ODBC modules to use the solutions above. There are other solutions I found listed [here](http://www.martin-evans.me.uk/node/20#perl). I maintain DBD::ODBC so I can obviously vouch for that working and I do all my testing with the Easysoft driver.

BTW, just so you know, I am affiliated with Easysoft and the web site link to the martin-evans domain is mine.